# Error while launching `pwgui` after istallation

Tags: gui

Wwhat can I do with the following error when I want to launch `pwgui`?

```
Command 'pwgui' not found, did you mean:

  command 'p2wgui' from deb pgn2web (0.4-2)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

This is  a clear hint that you do not have the command installed.
Open a terminal and type:

`sudo apt update & sudo apt install pgn2web`

Then try again `p2wgui`